# Cut first appearing pattern from line

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file say abc containing records like:

```
$cat xyz
    ABC
    ABCABC
    ABCABCABC
```

I want to cut first pattern so result should be like:

```
AC
ACABC
ACABCABC
```

I am trying to cut pattern using awk like:

```
$ cat xyz|awk -F 'B' '{print $1,$2}'
A CA
A CA
A CA
```

Of course, B is deliminator so i am getting above result. How could i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to delete first `B` in each line. If so, this will work:

```
sed 's/B//' xyx
```

Output:

```
AC
ACABC
ACABCABC
```

If you want the file to be replaced, add `-i`

```
sed -i 's/B//' xyx
```

---

I see you [tried to edit my answer to add a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1955058) - note that you have to do it updating your answer or writing in the comments.

> Thanks and if i have one more case that i want to delete first pattern
>   only if i have more than one repeated pattern like:
>
> ```
> $cat xyz
> ABC
> ABCABC
> ABCABCABC
> ```
>
> Output should be:
>
> ```
> ABC
> ACABC
> ACABCABC
> $cat xy
> ```

This can be a way to do it:

```
while read line
do
  if [ `echo $line | grep -o "B" | wc -l` -ge 2 ]
  then
     echo $line | sed 's/B//'
  else
     echo $line
  fi
done < xyz
```

Output:

```
ABC
ACABC
ACABCABC
```